# Как выполнить разделение пробелом разрядности чисел выводимых в инпут?

Tags: javascript

Есть ползунок на сайте , сделанный с пом ui slider joxi.ru/v29Xpo3IGnaepm .
Как можно выполнить разделение между числами в выводимом значении , чтобы было 2 500 000 , а 2500000 ?

Answer (score 1):

Если под ui slider имеешь ввиду jquery'вский, то вот...
В любом случае используй регулярку для результата.

```js
$("#slider").slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 1800000,
  max: 12000000,
  step: 500000,
  value: 1800000,
  slide: function() {
    val = '' + $('#slider').slider('value')
    $("#amount").val(val.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, "$1 "));
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly>
</p>

<div id="slider"></div>
```